# Coroutine example

Tags: javascript, generator, es6-promise, coroutine

In learning about coroutines in JavaScript, I can't wrap my head around the following [example](https://www.wptutor.io/web/js/generators-coroutines-async-javascript):

```js
coroutine(function* () {
  let posts = yield fetchPosts();
  let promises = posts.map(post => fetchComments(post));
  let comments = yield Promise.all(promises);
  displayComments(comments);
})

function coroutine(fn) {
  let gen = fn();
  let doNext = (data) => {
    let next = gen.next(data);
    if (!next.done) {
      return next.value.then(doNext);
    }
  };
  doNext();
}
```

It seems to me that on invoking `coroutine` in the above example, `doNext` will cumulatively be invoked twice.

When `coroutine` is invoked, the generator function halts execution on its first line `let posts = yield fetchposts();`; control is passed back to the `coroutine` function. At line `let next = gen.next(data);`, control is passed back to the generator function.

Now, to my understanding, `fetchposts` will, at this moment in time, have returned a Promise which includes *all* the posts. Hence this will be the first run of `doNext`.

The second run of `doNext` will commence when the generator function halts execution at the line `let comments = yield Promise.all(promises);`; handing control back to the `coroutine` function. At this moment in time, `next.value.then(doNext)` doesn't make sense to me anymore. I would expect `next.value` to be the Promise which would be able to resolve the comments.

Namely, `Promises.all(promises)` is passed back by the generator function. Hence this should resolve once all the comments are  fetched by the *post* Promises.

Obviously, I'm not seeing this correctly, since the explanation I gave doesn't comply with the actual execution of the invocation. What am I seeing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps to expand the recursive `doNext` function to visualise the flow of execution:

```
function* fn() {
  let posts = yield fetchPosts();
  let promises = posts.map(post => fetchComments(post));
  let comments = yield Promise.all(promises);
  displayComments(comments);
}

let gen = fn();
let data;
let next = gen.next(data); // data is undefined
                           // generator runs until first yield
                           // next.value becomes fetchPosts()
// assert(!next.done)
next.value.then(data => {
  let next = gen.next(data); // data is result of fetchPosts()
                             // generator runs until second yield:
                             //  posts becomes passed value (data)
                             //  promises becomes posts.map(…)
                             // next.value becomes Promise.all(…)
  // assert(!next.done)
  next.value.then(data => {
    let next = gen.next(data); // data is result of Promise.all(…)
                               // generator runs until the end:
                               //  comments becomes passed value (data)
                               //  comments are logged
                               // next.value becomes undefined
    // assert(next.done)
  });
});
```

Comment: So, on the second invocation of `next`, `next.value` is `Promise.all(promises)`. That is, of the two occurences of `next.value.then` in your code, the second one evaluates to `Promise.all(promises)`. *But since the `posts` variable is passed to the generator, by `gen.next(data)`, it gets assigned to the `comments` variable; because the second value to be passed to `gen.next` takes the place of the second yield inside the generator.* It seems that this is a bug in the code; the `comments` variable is supposed to be populated by the fulfillment value of `Promise.all(comments)`, not by`posts`.

Comment: @MusséRedi No. The second value to be passed to `gen.next()` takes the place of the **first** `yield`, and the third value to be passed to `gen.next()` takes the place of the second `yield`. I've updated to clarify.